# Show correct result with SQL Joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

Firstly, I am newbie to SQL (T-SQL), I would appreciate guidance with this.
I have 3 tables with values created as below.

```
CREATE Table StudentProject
(ID int identity (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
ProjectName Varchar (30),
DueDate Date)


CREATE Table StudentName 
(ID int identity (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
StudentName Varchar (30))

CREATE Table StudentWork
(ID int identity (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
ProjectID int,
StudentID int)

Insert Into StudentProject values 
('Omega','1/2/2005'),('KingOmega','1/3/2000'),('Beast','1/6/2007'), 
('DeltaMovie','3/7/2008')

Insert into StudentName values
('Roger'),('John'),('James'),('Juliet'),('William')

Insert into StudentWork values
(1,1),(1,2),(2,2),(2,3),(3,3),(3,4),(1,3)
```

The goal is to produce the below outcome but seems that i cant or i'm sure i'm doing something wrong.

**SQL_Outcom**

[image: SQL_Outcome]

Please help.

Comment: what have you tried so far? `inner join` is your solution

Comment: how did you know Roger is 1 and not 3 in the StudentName table  looking at your Studentwork table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use inner join and in order to match the records related to each others:

```
Select  p.ProjectName, s.StudentName  from StudentName  s
    Inner join Studentwork sw on sw.studentid = s.Id
    inner join StudentProject p on p.ID= sw.ProjectId
    Order by P.ProjectName desc
```

Comment: how did you know Roger is 1 and not 3 in the StudentName table looking at the Studentwork table?

Comment: The inner join would do the work based on the condition `sw.studentid = s.Id` and `p.ID= sw.ProjectId`, it would match the related ids, then get the names from corresponding tables

Comment: i get that... did you ask the OP how did he know the student ids?

Comment: what is the OP?

Comment: Thanks Coding - exactly what i wanted :)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT StudentProject.ProjectName, StudentName.StudentName
FROM StudentWork 
INNER JOIN StudentProject ON StudentProject.ID = StudentWork.ProjectID
INNER JOIN StudentName ON StudentName.ID = StudentWork.StudentID
```

You have 3 tables, try to recognize the "master table", then join them to other tables, after joining them you will have access to their columns.

Hello World :)

**UPDATE:**

In order to confirm Roger always with id 1 and all the other students in `StudentName` table, you need to use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` which guarantee you the ordering of rows.

Instead of :

```
Insert into StudentName values
('Roger'),('John'),('James'),('Juliet'),('William')
```

Do this:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT StudentName ON

Insert into StudentName values
(1,'Roger'),(2,'John'),(3,'James'),(4,'Juliet'),(5,'William')

SET IDENTITY_INSERT StudentName OFF
```

Comment: how did you know Roger is 1 and not 3 in the StudentName table looking at the Studentwork table?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu: Good point, I've made a terrible assumption that multi-row Insertion will guarantee ordering. My bad

Answer (score 2):

You need `inner join`

Try this :

```
select s.StudentName,p.ProjectName from StudentName s
inner join StudentProject sp on sp.id= sw.ProjectId
inner join StudentWork sw on sw.studentid = s.id;
```